# jump mechanic in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im currently making a game, and this is the jump mechanic.
the idea behind it is that it goes up for 500ms, waits for 200ms, and goes back to the ground (the ground is at top 471).
everything works now but it doesn't stop when its at top 471 i tried doing this:

```
if (characterTop > 471) {
    stopMoveDown()
}
```

that didn't work so then i tried doing this: (in the movingDown function)

```
if (characterTop > -1 || character < 471) {
    character.style.top = top + "px";
}
```

both of these didn't work.

and there is another problem, how can i make sure the player can't jump again while jumping?

this is the code i have now:

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
        jump = setInterval(function(){
            let top =
            parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
            top -= 1;

            var characterTop = parseInt(
                window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top")
            )

            if (characterTop > -1 || character < 471) {
                character.style.top = top + "px";
            }
        }, 1);

        setTimeout(function() {
            stopMoveUp()
        }, 500);

        setTimeout(function() {
            movingDown()
        }, 700);

        //if (characterTop > 471) {
        //    stopMoveDown()
        //}
    }
}

function movingDown() {
    falling = setInterval(function(){
        let top =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
        top += 1;

        var characterTop = parseInt(
            window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top")
        )

        if (characterTop > -1 || character < 471) {
            character.style.top = top + "px";
        }
    }, 1);
}

function stopMoveUp() {
    clearInterval(jump);
}

function stopMoveDown() {
    clearInterval(movingDown);
}

var movingRight = false;
var movingLeft = false;
```

can anybody please help me with these 2 problems?

Comment: I think you need to be checking for `top > 471` right?

Comment: no i already tried that